Set font size after writing the text?
The TL;DR of what I want:
Hi, I have what might be a slightly odd request that I'm not even sure is possible in LaTeX.  But I figured it can't hurt to ask:
I have some frame in Beamer like
\begin{frame}{Title}

Text 1.

\pause

Text 2.
\end{frame}

and it renders two slides.
What I want is for the first slide to have only "Text 1." is visible, and in a large font.  But in the second slide, "Text 1." is now in a small font, and "Text 2." is now visible in a large font.
And the pattern should continue: If there were another \pause with "Text 3." then on the third slide "Text 3." becomes visible and all previous text remains visible but shrinks.
I know I can accomplish this "manually" by not using \pause and instead building several different frames --- but then if I edit an earlier frame, the edit doesn't cascade to the later frames, making a management nightmare.  So I'm wondering if it's possible to automate this.
What I imagine that this requires is being able to write something like
\begin{frame}{Title}

Text 1.

\pause

\setTextAboveToSmall

Text 2.
\end{frame}

That is to say, once the \pause has been used to render a new slide, it applies a small font to everything above the line where the command \setTextAboveToSmall is.
That seems contrary to the fundamentals of how LaTeX works, but I wanted to ask just in case there's something I'm unaware of.
For the curious: why do I want this?
I would like to use Beamer to make slides, which may ultimately have a lot of text in them -- essentially because I want to put full proofs in the slide.  (This is for recording videos of math lectures.)
The slide may contain, for example, fifteen bullet points.  Displaying them at full size would (1) require the font to be so small as to be a strain to read, and (2) look like a wall of overwhelming text.  But I also don't want to display only some of the text and not others, because often I need to refer back to earlier things already established.
I feel like it might present well if whatever I'm talking about at a given moment is in large text, and everything else is in small text.  It emphasizes what I want the viewer to pay attention to, while also making it possible to quickly look back on earlier text if it's needed.

Fifteen bullet points in a single slide? The audience will be delighted!

the text will jump around as you move between slides and its location changes. this kind of jumping is the sort of undesirable effect overprint etc. are designed to avoid, but you can't use that if you are relying on shrinking to pack everything in. I suggest you make a few slides manually first to see what this will look like and decide if you are willing to inflict it on your audience, including members of your audience with visual impairments. it's actually pretty easy to achieve what you want, though you need different markup. just make an overlay-aware macro to change the size.

If it is helpful, I might note that I plan to export the PDFs and then use them inside of an app (Explain Everything) to do voice over and pen writing.  So it will not look like a standard slide show where the slide fits the screen and all you see is one slide after another.  There will be zooming, panning, annotation, and so on.  That might make the appearance not quite as horrible as it would if it were merely a slide show.

@Addem Please always post small, but compilable examples and not only code fragments.

Instead of trying to time travel to change previous text, you could instead use beamer actions to make parts of the text temporarily larger. Here an example with a list:
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment{grayenv}{\only{\Huge}}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}[<gray@+>]
  \item[] test
  \item[] test
  \item[] test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



It's an interesting solution!  However, if one wants to gray out or entirely hide future text, one would have to make that the default text ... and then it applies to the entire document.  Or the work-around I can imagine is graying all text inside a slide manually, but again that's a bit un-desirable (but perhaps necessary?).  Anyway, thank you for this!

@Addem You can still gray out text.
